# How can I pass a value to init methods on import?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Let's assume I have component like this:

```
'use strict';

export default () => ({
    selected: false,
    init(selectedIndex: -1)
    {

    }

});
```

and I import it like this (using AlpineJS 3):

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'

window.Alpine = Alpine

window.Components = {};

import Tab from "./components/Tab";
window.Components.Tab = Tab;

Alpine.start();
```

How can I now pass value to `init` method?

When I have:

```
<div x-data="Components.Tab(0)">...</div>
```

value is obviously not passed to `init` method.

Although there is info in docs how to [register component from a bundle](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#registering-from-a-bundle) and info how to [pass initial parameters](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#initial-parameters), there is no info how to pass initial parameters to component registered from a bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [the documentation of the init function](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#init-functions):

> If your component contains an `init()` method

you cannot add parameters to the `init()` method (notice the two brackets that mean no parameters).

The parameters have to be added to the component itself. So your component definition should be:

```
'use strict';

export default (initialSelected = -1) => ({
    selected: initialSelected,
    init()
    {

    }

});
```

BTW, I noticed that your `selected` field is boolean while your `selectedIndex` parameter is numerical. In my corrected code above I just used numerical for both.

Also, you have used this in your code:

```
window.Components.Tab = Tab;
```

But [the documentation you have linked to](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#registering-from-a-bundle) says you need to use `Alpine.data('Tab', Tab)` to register from a bundle.

Comment: Thanks. I've used this to add additional "properties" and then in `init` method I use them to set other "real" properties